Detect what app uses a comport - potentially for a vmware escape via a comport/named pipe ntoskrnl
How could I diagnose if this named pipe that goes to com1 in vmware (now to a txt file) is malware or a legitimate piece of software?
Are there anyways to track what sends data to a comport in windows 10
The named pipe is sending things like this
SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exeNULª0000BELNULDC2SOHNULBS... lots more
Lots of NULs and padding (I won't include the full txt as it might have identifying information in there)
'omitted'      KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
'omitted'      KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
Detecting what is opening the named pipe/comport on windows startup would likely be all I need to determine the answer to this.
Some background info here on windows kernel debugging using
https://voidsec.com/windows-drivers-reverse-engineering-methodology/
